# Getting plain text instead of Python script execution

Tags: python, nginx, virtualenv, uwsgi

I'm trying to execute this little request with jquery on a page load:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/static/query.py",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $(body).text(data);
    }
});
```

On a server running nginx, python, in a virtualenv, working with Flask framework and the return is the query.py sourcecode, not the data retrieved from the DB.

query.py is marked as executable and the script has the shebang:

```
#!/home/gabriel/project/bin
```

which points to the bin in my virtualenv. I think got the basis covered but yet, the problem persists.

Tips?

More info:

Flask script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
def init():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

uwsgi.py to load the Flask script:

```
from myapp import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

The query.py:

```
from db import * //Database model, SQLAlchemy.

def something():
    data = Kingdom.query.all()
    return data

something()
```

Comment: there's nothing in your setup to run the script. The request is completely 'static'. When you say 'running python' what does that mean? What's the framework python is running? Flask, Django? Something else? There should be a mechanism that serves the 'static/query.py' route. Pointing to a file will just serve that file (NGINX is doing that, python is not involved in your setup in any way).

Comment: I'm working with Flask.

Comment: please post the relevant flask code, we'll figure it out..

Comment: I'll look at it once i reach home, but i followed this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

and the initial Python worked, it loaded the main Template page when '/'. I'm starting to believe with your comments this is a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be running the actual code that's in query.py inside flask. Do something like:

```
@application.route("/query"):
def get_data():
    .. whatever code you need; currently in query.py, you would probably use sqlalchemy/ flask-sqlalchemy
    data =  your data (dictionary? list?) 
    return jsonify(data=data) # flask will turn your data into a proper JSON string to send back as a response to the ajax call.
```

Don't forget to import jsonify from flask, consult docs [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#module-flask.json).
Also rename "/static/query.py" to "/query" in example above, or anything else you see fit. You can also send flask parameters via the AJAX call to process in your query; e.g., filtering parameters. Focus the question for further guidance.